# Should I use 1,15 or */15 in crontab to run a command every 15 days?

Tags: cron

As I know crontab has those fields, starting by left to right.

```
1   minutes 0-59
2   hours 0-23
3   days of month 0-31
4   month 1-12
5   day of the week 0-6
6   command
```

I want to run foo command every 15 days at 15:30
This is correct because run command 1 and 15 of the month
month has 30 days(31 some) so is run every 15 days

```
30 15 1,15 * * /sbin/foo -a 1> /dev/null
```

Is also correct this syntax?

```
30 15 */15 * * /sbin/foo -a 1> /dev/null
```

System is Slackware Linux which use Dillon Cron

Comment: There is no "mail-to" field; there's a `MAILTO` variable, but you set that on a line by itself (before the job entries that it applies to).

Comment: The mailto doesn't work on cron dillon, cron.log said "Nov 20 20:06:01  crond[1634]: failed parsing crontab for user root: MAILTO=root 
"

Comment: Interesting; I don't have a copy to experiment with, but from [the docs](https://github.com/dubiousjim/dcron/blob/master/crontab.1) it looks like Dillon cron doesn't support *any* variables in crontab files.

Comment: `30 15 */2 * 0` should give a nice 14 day rhythm, depending on the job that might also be an option.

Comment: For an alternative see `man systemd.timer`. I like the `Persistent` feature: _"This is useful to catch up on missed runs of the service when the system was powered down."_

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This syntax `30 15 */15 * *` is correct, but it is not doing the same with this `30 15 1,15 * *`.

The latter will execute command at `1st` and `15th` of the month, as it has fixed comma separated values for the "day of month" field.

The `/` defines steps, that means `*/15` will execute every `15` days, starting from `1`, that means: `1st`, `16th` (for all months) and also `31th` (for any month having 31 days).

---

As `man crontab(5)` says, step  values  can  be used in conjunction with ranges. So if you want to have the same result using the `/` syntax you could do: `30 15 1-15/14 * *` which means `30 15 1,15 * *`.

Another example, if you want to run every 15 days, but on 5th and 20th of every month: `5-20/15`. Of course, for this case, it is more readable to write `5,20`. But combining the range with the steps, enables defining the start-end of the ranged execution.

For Day 1,3,5,7 etc of the Month: `*/2`

For Day 2,4,6,8 etc of the Month: `2-30/2`

For Minutes(`0-59`) and Hours(`0-23`), the first valid value is `0` so this: `0 */2 * * *` means at `00:00`, `02:00`, `04:00` etc.

Comment: I thought `*/n` means every multiple of `n`. Or is that only for fields whose values start at 0?

Comment: Yes, for minute or hour, `*/n` (without a range at the "dividend") will start from `0`, so it is the multiple of `n`. For Day Of Month, where `1` is the first valid value, it starts from 1, so it is "multiple of n" +1.